# How to use different object in javascript on click?

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, I have two arrays called "array1" and "array2".

I set currentArrray to be array1. Later when user clicks on some button, currentArray switches to Array2 and back to array1 if I click on it again.

This way, whenever there is any part of the code that needs to use an array, I just use something like in pseudocode:

```
{currentArray}.getText;
{currentArray}.getText;
```

Is it possible to do something like this? If so, how?
I know you can use if statement, but because currentArray is used in different parts of code, it would be nice if I had a simple way like this where all I have to modify is currentArray variable so I dont have if statements scattered all over the place checking what currentArray is.

Comment: It would help if you would post more of the psuedocode illustrating what you want to do, because the apparent answer to this question seems too obvious.

Comment: Somehow I don't get it. You say you are already "using" some code (setting the array) but later asking whether it is possible? What do you currently have and what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable called "currentArray" and just set it to refer to whatever other array you want.

```
var currentArray;

currentArray = array2;
```

If you've got some function that refers to a particular global variable:

```
function foo() {
  // something something
  var x = array1[2];
  // ...
}
```

Then it's going to refer to "array1" no matter what.  You can change the value of "array1" of course, but you can't make that function refer to "array2" any other way.  Functions in JavaScript are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are asking for.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/5Tc7P/)

```
var currentArray,
    arr1 = [1, 2, 3],
    arr2 = [4, 5, 6];

$('button').click(function(e) {
    currentArray = currentArray == arr1 ? arr2 : arr1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have array object provided in Javascript. You may use it if you want to create one. Else use anything that DOM provides.

You may have to do something like this.

```
var my_array = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   my_array[i] = source_array[i];
}
var x = my_array[4];
```

It is also possible to copy simply,

```
my_array = souce_array;
```

However this would simply copy the reference.